# Sharing on instagram with bypassing the instagram menu (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, instagram, share

I am developing an app, where I am able to share to instagram, but I want to share **directly** to the instagram story.

At the moment, when I am trying to share the picture, it is opening the instagram story menu and then I have to click again to share.

Is there a way to bypass this section.

Code:

```
private let instagramStoriesURL = URL(string: "instagram-stories://share")

   public func postToInstagramStories(image: UIImage, backgroundTopColorHex: String, backgroundBottomColorHex: String, deepLink: String) {

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

                guard let urlScheme = self.instagramStoriesURL else {
                    self.delegate?.error(message: "URL not valid")
                    return
                }

                let pasteboardItems = ["com.instagram.sharedSticker.stickerImage": image,
                                       "com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundTopColor" : backgroundTopColorHex,
                                       "com.instagram.sharedSticker.backgroundBottomColor" : backgroundBottomColorHex,
                                       "com.instagram.sharedSticker.contentURL": deepLink] as [String : Any]

                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    let pasteboardOptions = [UIPasteboard.OptionsKey.expirationDate : NSDate().addingTimeInterval(60 * 5)]
                    UIPasteboard.general.setItems([pasteboardItems], options: pasteboardOptions)

                } else {
                    UIPasteboard.general.items = [pasteboardItems]
                }
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    UIApplication.shared.open(urlScheme, options: [:], completionHandler: { (success) in
                        self.delegate?.success()
                    })
                } else {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(urlScheme)
                    self.delegate?.success()
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: it is working with the UIViewController, as this is automatically sharing to your Facebook or Twitter feed.
Check on your phone (gallery) and try to share a picture directly from there.
But I also don't know how this is actually working.